# Matlab: How to add data to specific row number in a uitable

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

**Question 1**

I wrote a gui code that gives the following row which is then made to display on a uitable:

```
combt =

Columns 1 through 5

2000    2530.4    2671.4    2.3   2.6
```

This row will be automatically added to row 1 in the uitable:

[image: See here]

In my example above, I would like this row to be added to row 2000 (depending on column 1 of my data).

Therefore if my row has a `column_1 = 10`, I would like this row to appear at row 10 in the uitable and so on. I have been looking for this answer for over a year so your help will be much appreciated.

**Question 2:**

Say I have a table with the following numbers

```
combt =

Columns 1 through 5

1    2630.4    2671.4    5.3   2.6
2    2530.2    2673.4    2.2   6.6
10   2331.4    4671.2    4.3   2.7
11   2550.4    6671.4    2.1   2.8
```

How can rearrange them so that ,again, column 1 corresponds to the row number and the spaces are filled with zeros as such:

```
combt =

Columns 1 through 5

1    2630.4    2671.4    5.3   2.6
2    2530.2    2673.4    2.2   6.6
0    0         0         0     0       (This is row 3)
0    0         0         0     0       (This is row 4)
0    0         0         0     0       (This is row 5)
0    0         0         0     0       (This is row 6)
0    0         0         0     0       (This is row 7)
0    0         0         0     0       (This is row 8)
0    0         0         0     0       (This is row 9)
10   2331.4    4671.2    4.3   2.7
11   2550.4    6671.4    2.1   2.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new_d(d(:,1),:)=d` to create your new required matrix `new_d`. Here is a sample code.

```
d = [1    2630.4    2671.4    5.3   2.6; ...
2    2530.2    2673.4    2.2   6.6; ...
10   2331.4    4671.2    4.3   2.7; ...
11   2550.4    6671.4    2.1   2.8];

new_d(d(:,1),:)=d;

% with first column
f = figure();
t = uitable(f,'Data',new_d);

% without showing first column
f1 = figure();
t1 = uitable(f1,'Data',new_d(:,2:end));
```

Update `uitable` with new data :

```
%% update table
% new data containing same first column value 10 and 2 
d1 = [14    2630.4    2671.4    5.3   2.6; ...   
18    2530.2    2673.4    2.2   6.6; ...
10   3333.4    2671.2    3.3   1.7; ...
2   2331.4    4671.2    4.3   2.7];

% update data 
new_d(d1(:,1),:)=d1;

% update uitable with first column
set(t,'Data',new_d);

% update uitable without showing first column
set(t1,'Data',new_d(:,2:end));
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to amend this table, i.e. if I acquire more rows, I would like to add them to the existing table. Also, I would like the acquired rows with the the same value in column 1 to overwrite the old ones.

Comment: Thank you, but this is still overwriting everything, producing a fresh table